# Searching for a particular letter sequence in an Excel spreadsheet row using Python 2.7 and xlrd

Tags: excel, python-2.7, parsing, unicode, xlrd

I just started using xlrd in Python 2.7.12 and cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong; seems like a data type mismatch.

Basically, I'm searching an Excel spreadsheet (.xlsx) for a sequence of letters in a series of rows that are two columns wide, and if found, I'd like to copy that entire row into a new spreadsheet.

The data in the spreadsheet looks like...

```
R1: TheName_of_the_thing_XYZQ , Description of the thing with keyword1
R1: TheName_of_another_thing_61PD , Description of the thing with keyword2
```

And here's what I've got so far...

```
import xlrd

search_for = ['XYZQ', 'keyword2', 'foo', 'FOO']

book = xlrd.open_workbook('csv-test.xlsx')
i = 0
j = 0

sheet1 = book.sheet_by_index(1)

for i in range(sheet1.nrows):
     row = sheet1.row_values(i)
     for j in range(len(row)):
          if row[j] == search_for:
                print 'found it!'
          else:
            print 'sorry'
```

When I run this, it never finds anything in search_for, just prints 'sorry' for every row.

So I do know that it opens the correct document, parses each row, etc. I have also tried cell_value and row_slice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your error is in these lines:

```
if row[j] == search_for:
```

In your case, `row[j]` is the content of the cell in Unicode format, and search_for is the list declared at the beginning.

In other words, you have this situation, for example:

```
if u'TheName_of_the_thing_XYZQ' == ['XYZQ', 'keyword2', 'foo', 'FOO']:
```

and doesn't work.

I modified your script as following loop inside the `searc_for` list and checking if the single cell contains one of the elements of the list.

```
import xlrd
search_for = ['XYZQ', 'keyword2', 'foo', 'FOO']
book = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

for idx in range(sheet.nrows):
    row = sheet.row_values(idx)
    name = row[0]
    description = row[1]
    print "==== row number {} ====".format(idx + 1)
    for key in search_for:
        if key in name:
            print "in 'name' column, found {}".format(name)
        if key in description:
            print "in 'description' column, found {}".format(name)
```

Let me know

Comment: That works perfectly, Giordano! Thank you! The next thing I have to do is, if I find a match in either column, I want to copy both columns in that row to another spreadsheet. I think I can figure that out, but if you have any quick thoughts, please let me know!

Comment: Glad to help you! btw, to write an Excel file, you can use xlsxwriter package. it's simple and you can find simply examples or tutorials online.
If you are in trouble, feel free to contact me on twitter/github (see my profile)